# expand users table with django

Tags: python, django

I'm using the authentication that ships with django, and as such, it comes with its own SQL table. I have a few more attributes I'd like to use with the User model that are custom to my app such as a user photo or a random user blob where users can type in notes.

what's the best way of extending the existing user table that ships with django's authentication/authorization modeling to allow for my custom fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Please see my (and others) answer to this question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576345/django-project-structure-recommended-structure-to-share-an-extended-auth-user/576362#576362)

Answer (score 0):

The other way to handle this is to do table inheritance on the User model and develop your own derived EnhancedUser model.  Typically a custom wrapper backend is also written to make sure the auth subsystem returns the EnhancedUser model as well.

There's a very good [blog post answer here](http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/).